# How to create a color box in front of a radiobutton in html?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I want to create a radiobutton with a small color box in front of it.
This is the current code that I have written:

```
<label class="container"  style="color: #0B9BCD">
   <div class="foo"></div>
   <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="highlight1" value="highlight1"/>               
   <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

where the class foo has the following style:

```
.foo {
     float: left;
     width: 20px;
     height: 20px;
     margin: 5px;
     border: 1px solid black;
     background: #13b4ff;
  }
```

And the output I am getting is something like this:

[image]

How can I move the color box to the right of the radiobutton?

Comment: Would you like to have the dot right next to your box or inside?

Comment: On the left side of the box, not inside

Comment: Try changing "margin: 5px" to "margin: 0px 5px 5px 5px". This sets the top margin to 0px.

Comment: That doesn't help, the checkbox still remains on the right side of the box.

Comment: I think it might be wise to rephrase your question. Be clear about what you want to achieve, maybe with an image showing the desired result. (Also, are you talking about a checkbox or a radio button?)

Comment: Oops sorry, I meant to write radio button. I changed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By moving the div with className "foo" below the radio input and giving the container a `display: flex property` we can achieve the desired solution.
follow this link to know more about the flexbox.
https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/

```
<label class="container">
  <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="highlight1" value="highlight1" />
  <div class="foo"></div>
</label>

.foo {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #13b4ff;
}

.container{
  display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the order. Your foo is ordered before your input.

Comment: Only moving the foo line after the input does not change the output. But using the display: flex property as suggested by Prakhar achieves the required change.